# Why vulkan can't support same time use multi subpass and second commandbuffers?

Tags: vulkan

Why subpass contents can't at the same time support VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE and VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_SECONDARY_COMMAND_BUFFERS?  I want to use gbuffer and second command buffers to render scene.

Comment: "*I want to use gbuffer and second command buffers to render scene.*" What's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: I want the first subpass to generate scene gbuffer, in this subpass I want to use multithread second command buffer, then the next subpass process subpass input gbuffer data. but subpass contents can't at the same time support VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE and VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_SECONDARY_COMMAND_BUFFERS.

Comment: ... again, I do not see what the problem is. What commands *need* to be inline in this process? If you want to generate commands on this thread for this subpass, just put them in a secondary CB. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Because the specification says so.  Put your inline commands into one or more separate secondary command buffers.

Long version:

> Why subpass contents can't at the same time support VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE and VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_SECONDARY_COMMAND_BUFFERS?

If you're asking why you literally can't combine them, it's because they're not bit flags, but a sequence.  Bit flags, like [VkBufferUsageFlagBits](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkBufferUsageFlagBits.html) will typically have values that  each represent a single bit in a 32 bit value.

Sequences like [VkSubpassContents](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkSubpassContents.html) have values that start at 0 and increment by 1 each time (although extension provided values will often jump ahead).

Since `VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE` is literally 0, there's no way to combine it with `VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_SECONDARY_COMMAND_BUFFERS`, which is literally 1.

If you're asking why `VkSubpassContents` is a sequence and not a bit flag, that's just the way the specification is. It might seem like having a subpass include both inline commands and secondary buffers might be trivial, but it probably only *seems* that way to people using the API, as opposed to be people who have to implement the backend.  Likely it either created some potential ambiguity, or would have made some threading edge case a nightmare to implement, or something similar.

> I want to use gbuffer and second command buffers to render scene.

As Nicol points out in his comments, there's nothing stopping you from doing that. Whatever inline commands you're trying to use along with your secondary command buffers, you can just put into **another** secondary buffer. If this is somehow problematic because you're interleaving lots of inline statements with where you want to execute your secondary buffers, well that sounds more like a design problem, like maybe you're trying to execute work in a subpass that doesn't belong there.